# Finding Recurrence relations for combinatorics problems

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

After you graduate you accept a job that promises a starting salary of $40,000$ and a raise at the end of each year equal to $5\%$ of your current salary plus $1000$. For example, your raise at the end of the first year is $3000$. Let $S_n$ be your salary after $n$ years, so that $S_0 = 40,000$.

A- Find a recurrence relation.

B- Determine how much you will be making after $2$ years, after $5$ years, after $10$ years.

I did part A.  I don't know if I did it correctly, so it's $S_{n+1} = S_n \cdot 1.05+1000$ with $S_0=40,000$.

Comment: Did you mean $S_{n + 1} = S_n \cdot 1.05 + 1000$ with $S_0 = 40,000$?

Comment: S_{n+1}= 1.05 +1000 with S_0= 40,000 yes

Comment: The formula to which you said yes is correct.  Was that your question?

Comment: So how do you do part B.

Comment: Can you make a formula just for adding 1000 a year? Can you make a formula for a 5% increase? If you can do them separately, now what? Edit: remember, after the first placement of the 1000, it will start getting 5% too, so not so easy, think of it like an annuity if you've done those before.

Comment: I've never done annuity before

Comment: Ok, can you just try it for 2 years using your recurrence relation?

Comment: So is it 40,000 * 1.05 +4000?

Comment: Not really. You already said it's 43,000 after one year. So now do one year more using 43,000 to start.

Comment: 43,000 *1.05 +1000

Comment: Excellent. Now just continue on until 5 and 10 years. Or you can look at a more advanced way to do it in the nice answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&S_{n} = 1.05\,S_{n - 1} + 1000 \implies
S_{n} + 20000 = 1.05\pars{S_{n - 1} + 20000}
\\[5mm]
& \implies
\bbx{\ds{S_{n} = 1.05^{\,n}\pars{S_{0} + 20000} - 20000} =
20000\pars{3 \times 1.05^{\,n} - 1}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{S_{2} = 46,150\,;\quad S_{5} = 56,576.9\,;\quad S_{10} = 77,733.7}$.

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence relation 
\begin{align*}
S_0 & = 40,000\\
S_{n + 1} & = S_n \cdot 1.05 + 1000
\end{align*}
that you stated is correct.

Let's look at the first few terms of the sequence.
\begin{align*}
S_1 & = S_0 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
    & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
S_2 & = S_1 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
    & = (40,000 \cdot 1.05 + 1000) \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
    & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^2 + 1000 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
S_3 & = S_2 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
    & = (40,000 \cdot 1.05^2 + 1000 \cdot 1.05 + 1000) \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
    & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^3 + 1000 \cdot 1.05^2 + 1000 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\
    & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^3 + 1000(1.05^2 + 1.05 + 1)
\end{align*}
If we use the geometric series formula 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} r^{k - 1} = 1 + r + r^2 + \cdots r^{n - 1} = \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$
we can express $S_3$ in the form 
$$S_3 = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^3 + 1000 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.05^3}{1 - 1.05}$$
Can you find a formula for $S_n$?

Comment: So it will be 43,000*1.05 +1000 for the 2nd year

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So I'm getting confused on the 5th year isn't it, 46150*1.05^2+1000*1.05+1000?

Comment: I would use the formula $$S_n = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^n + 1000 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.05^n}{1 - 1.05}$$ to calculate $S_5$ and $S_{10}$.

Comment: I was trying to find the formula for S_n didn't work out with me

Comment: Observe that \begin{align*} S_4 & = S_3 \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\ & = [40,000 \cdot 1.05^3 + 1000(1.05^2 + 1.05 + 1)] \cdot 1.05 + 1000\\ & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^4 + 1000(1.05^3 + 1.05^2 + 1.05) + 1000\\ & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^4 + 1000(1.05^3 + 1.05^2 + 1.05 + 1)\\ & = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^4 + 1000 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.05^4}{1 - 1.05}\end{align*}  If you generalize what I just did you obtain the formula I wrote above.

Comment: I'm so confused so what's the answer for 5 years and 10 years

Comment: For five years, $$S_5 = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^5 + 1000 \cdot \frac{1 - 1.05^5}{1 - 1.05} = 56576.89375$$ Rounding to the nearest cent yields $56,576.89$.  For ten years, $$S_{10} = 40,000 \cdot 1.05^{10} + 1000 \cdot {1 - 1.05^{10}}{1 - 1.05} = 77733.6776066$$ Rounding to the nearest cent yields $77,733.68$, although it may be a bit optimistic to round up.

Comment: That's what I got thanks for the all this help, your amazing bro